# Table "catalog_product_super_link" and "catalog_product_relation" shows wrong parent-child records

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento2

Trying to get parent-child relation through mysql query in my extension but wrong detail stored in "catalog_product_super_link" and "catalog_product_relation".

Example

```
+---------+------------+-----------+
| link_id | product_id | parent_id |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|       6 |     249594 |        54 |
|       9 |     249597 |        54 |
|      12 |     249600 |        54 |
|      15 |     249603 |        54 |
|      18 |     249606 |        54 |
|      21 |     249609 |        54 |
|      24 |     249612 |        54 |
|      27 |     249618 |        84 |
|      30 |     249621 |        84 |
|      33 |     249624 |        84 |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

There is no product with entity_id "54" in "catalog_product_super_link" but still we have a record for it even after reindexing.

Comment: Please paste the table content as formatted text in your question and not as screenshot, thanks.

Comment: Please share screen shot of product listing